# Accidental removal of some laravel files with composer install/update, how to retrieve?

Tags: php, laravel-4, composer-php

I was trying to move the packages from my `require-dev` to `require` in composer.json, and accidentally created a second `require` object when there was already one above the `autoload`  object and called `composer update`. It then began deleting my laravel install and I quickly pressed ctrl+c.

But now I'm getting an error saying `Fatal error: Interface 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface' not found` when I visit my website, or try running composer install/update again.

Is there any way to recover from this?

These are teh files that were deleted:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\project>composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Removing laravel/framework (v4.1.18)
  - Removing classpreloader/classpreloader (1.0.1)
  - Removing d11wtq/boris (v1.0.8)
  - Removing ircmaxell/password-compat (1.0.3)
  - Removing filp/whoops (1.0.10)
  - Removing jeremeamia/superclosure (1.0.1)
  - Removing nikic/php-parser (v0.9.4)
  - Removing monolog/monolog (1.7.0)
  - Removing nesbot/carbon (1.8.0)
  - Removing patchwork/utf8 (v1.1.17)
  - Removing phpseclib/phpseclib (0.3.5)
  - Removing predis/predis (v0.8.5)
  - Removing stack/builder (v1.0.1)
  - Removing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v5.0.3)
  - Removing symfony/browser-kit (v2.4.1)
  - Removing symfony/css-selector (v2.4.1)
  - Removing symfony/dom-crawler (v2.4.1)
  - Removing symfony/http-kernel (v2.4.1)
^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? y
```

Comment: I've tried composer dump-autoload and then composer install, but same error. If I can install a fresh copy of laravel (i.e. like updating it) that would be great as well

Comment: Also tried composer require laravel/framework:4.1.*, but no avail

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't worry, you shouldn't loose anything of your application. It was basically removing things in the vendor folder, which are pretty much removable at any time without prejudice for your application source files, but yes, without them your application will not work, so:

Just get your composer.json back in its feets:

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
},
```

Completely remove your vendor folder:

```
del C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\*.* /s
```

And then:

```
composer update
```

Again

Comment: Hi Antonio, I tried that but got the same fatal error. The "require" object was there in composer.json all along, but the mistake I made was adding another "require" object later on in the file. I was really worried so I took the easy way out and got a fresh install of Laravel and copied my views/controllers/routes/etc to it. Thank you for the reply nonetheless

Comment: Ok, added one more step, delete your vendor folder. Okay, nice. :)

Comment: Yes I believe the delete would have done the trick. I knew the problem was the missing http kernel, and I'm sure this would have solved it instead of my long procedure. I'm marking as accepted